# How can I extract text from specific elements if HTML page using certain values present

Tags: python, selenium

```
<td class="error-snip-cell xdata-label-text">7 - Partner Specific</td>
<td class="error-id-cell xdata-label-text">0x39394C1</td>
<td class="error-snip-cell xdata-label-text">7 - Partner Specific</td>
<td class="error-id-cell xdata-label-text">0x39394C1</td>
<td class="error-snip-cell xdata-label-text">4 - Situational</td>
<td class="error-id-cell xdata-label-text">0x3938BF3</td>
<td colspan="2" class="error-message-cell xdata-value-text">Trace Number should not 
be used.</td>
<td class="error-snip-cell xdata-label-text">2 - H Syntax</td>
<td class="error-id-cell xdata-label-text">0x81004C</td>
<td colspan="2" class="error-message-cell xdata-value-text">A data loop with 'Must Use' status 
is missing.</td>
```

Above is what I have in HTML and there are more tags like above.
I am trying to find error-snip-cell xdata-label-text = 2 - H Syntax and 4 - Situational. If these exists on the page then get me value or text of error-id-cell xdata-label-text and error-message-cell xdata-value-text.
There are more HTML tags with the text I am looking in page. How can I get all the text or values, I am looking based on specific things I am looking using selenium python?

Comment: why don't you try to locate by text? [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-selenium-find-element-by-text/)

Answer (score 0):

You can build xpath to find the Elements using the `class` and the `text` it has.

```
#since I dont know under which the table appears have used "//..td". And if trying to find an element within in an element use a dot at the beginning.(".//td")
# for "error-snip-cell xdata-label-text = 2 - H Syntax"
//..td[contains(@class,'error-id-cell') and contains(text(),'Syntax')]
# can also be like
//..td[starts-with(@class,'error-id-cell') and ends-with(text(),'Syntax')]

# for "error-snip-cell xdata-label-text = 4 - Situational"
//..td[contains(@class,'error-id-cell') and contains(text(),'Situational')]
# can also be like
//..td[starts-with(@class,'error-id-cell') and ends-with(text(),'Situational')]

# for "text of error-id-cell xdata-label-text and error-message-cell xdata-value-text. "
//..td[contains(@class,'error-id-cell')]
//..td[contains(@class,'error-message-cell')]
```